# How do I translate this HTML/ViewBag dropdownlist to Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, .net, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

How would I go around to translate this piece of code which is based on a ViewBag foreach that produces pure HTML. To a Html.DropDownList based on a Model?

My HTML right now looks like this

```
<select id="drpProject" name="drpProject">
       <option value="Blank" selected="selected">-- Select Project --</option>
       @foreach (SolutionName.ViewModel.project project in ViewBag.lstProject)
       {
           <option value="@project.id">@project.projectName</option>
       }
</select>
```

But I want to use @Html.DropDownList or @Html.DropDownListFor since I'm using @Html.TextBoxFor for my textboxes but not for my dropdownlists

Like I want this instead

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.projectID)
```

The model in question is @Model.projectID which is an integer
But I want to display the projectName while the value is the projectID.
I also would like to have a blank option at the start as default if it is possible with @Html.DropDownList?

Here is the controller code

```
List<project> lstProject = projectModel.getSetProjectCache(); //Get from SQL function
ViewBag.lstProject = lstProject;
```

Comment: show us the controller code for creating dropdownlist

Comment: @janina I create the dropdownlist in the view, not controller. I only get the list in the controller and send it to the view with a ViewBag. Anyway added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller create the viewbag like below

```
ViewBag.lstProject = new SelectList(lstProject,"projectID","projectName");
```

Now in the view just use below,You will get the dropdown as expected nothing more is needed

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.projectID,ViewBag.lstProject as SelectList,"")
```

Comment: Yes, this works a bit better. 
Is it possible to change the visible text on the first/default blank post?